# Linear Independence of random binary vectors

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

Suppose we have $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $n$ independent random vectors ($m \geq n$),  where the entries of each $Y_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables taking the values $\{0, 1\}$ with equal probability.  I am interested in estimates for the probability that the $Y_i$'s are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.  Or more generally, for $k \leq n$, what is the probability that for all subsets $S \subset [n]$ of size $k$, that $\{ Y_i : i \in S\}$ are linearly independent.

I have found some references that answer related questions.  This post has references that speak on the asymptotic probability of a random square $\{0, 1\}$ matrix being invertible: [Number of invertible {0,1} real matrices?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices)

Most notably it includes this reference ( https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0461 ) that shows the probability that a $n \times n$ random $\{0,1\}$ matrix is singular is $\mathcal{O}\left((\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + o(1))^n \right)$.  Using this I can get some crude asymptotic estimates, but I am searching for a non-asymptotic result ideally.

Similar problems have been investigated where the independence is instead over $\mathbb{F}^2$:
[Expected number of random binary vectors so that the form a basis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140090/expected-number-of-random-binary-vectors-so-that-the-form-a-basis)

Most notably this one:
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Number-of-Linearly-Independent-Binary-Vectors-Damelin-Michalski/15630b8ad6de8f245e5ea9c52a3a757bd98d701e

I am interested in any references that offer any tools that might help with this problem.  I am most interested in the case when $m$ is a large constant multiple of $n$.  Thank you.

Comment: Nice fact: if $K$ is a subfield of $L$ and $S$ is a collection of vectors in $K^n$. Then $S$ is linearly independent over $K$ if and only if $S$ is independent over $L$. (Proof: consider the system of linear equations $\sum a_sx_s=0$ and write it as $Xa=0$ where $A$ is a $n\times |S|$ matrix with entries in $K$. Then the rank of $A$ over $K$ may be obtained by row reduction, but one obtains the same matrix if one row reduces over $L$). Hence you can just ask about independence over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: If $m$ is large relative to $n$ then the $\mathbb{F}^2$ answer is already quite small (should be on the order of $2^{n-m}$), and is also an upper bound for the answer over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @KevinP.Costello thank you; that would be great.  I thought I was able to prove such a bound for a second, but I made a mistake.  Do you have a reference or a sketch of an argument?  I am probably missing something simple...

Comment: If $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are independent, the probability that $v_{k+1}$ lies in their span is $2^{k-m}$.  (This is the observation used by Douglas Zare in the linked answer; if your existing vectors form a $k$ dimensional space, there's $k$ coordinates that parameterize it, so $2^k$ vectors in the space out of $2^m$ total).  Adding up over all $k$ and using the union bound, the probability that your vectors fail to be independent is at most $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{k-m} < 2^{n-m}$$

Comment: @KevinP.Costello Excellent thanks.  I now understand completely.